# C# how dereferencing works behind the scenes

Tags: c#, pointers, reference, ref, dereference

This code is from book named "Pro C# with .NET 6" and I wonder what happens behind the scenes while the reference to reference(ref Person p) is passed to the method. for example when we do p.personAge = 555; does dereferencing happen twice behind the scenes to first get to the variable which is being pointed to by p and then to get to value which the variable pointed by p contains? sorry if question is bit confusing but overall I want to know how dereferencing works in C#, in this case do we have 2 way dereferencing which happens automatically by the compiler?

```cs
static void SendAPersonByReference(ref Person p)
{
 // Change some data of "p".
 p.personAge = 555;
...
}
```

does dereferencing happens in this code too?

```cs
static void SendAPersonByReference(Person p)
{
 // Change some data of "p".
 p.personAge = 555;
...
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://godbolt.org/z/xfvE8aKeG

Comment: @RobertHarvey can you clarify what happens? I don't understand assembly well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a double-dereference; this is encoded in the IL; see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEBGJAAkJTIGUYA7AEwEEAFGKAZwjoCEBPAEowAZu3pgYACljCybTtzIAHAJQBYAFABvTWQD0esgGEAFgEM6AcxhkuAWxsMzGM2QiyAREo8A6XUp8ldi46JmsyAF4yAFZYgG5NAF9NFI0SckoaemZ5EP4ANTNcAFcpXMVVTR0NfUNTC3D7R2dXdzIvX39A4O4wmyjY6ISNZI1NQgAmOR66MmqyBYoAZjJsOgxlGb7hxKA===), with the key portion being:

(by-reference)

```
    IL_0000: ldarg.0 # load the value of p, a ref-ref-Person (push 1)
    IL_0001: ldind.ref # dereference the ref-ref to a ref-Person (pop 1, push 1)
    IL_0002: ldc.i4 555 # load the constant integer 555 (push 1)
    IL_0007: stfld int32 Person::personAge # store to field (pop 2)
    IL_000c: ret
```

vs (by value)

```
    IL_0000: ldarg.0 # load the value of p, a ref-Person (push 1)
    IL_0001: ldc.i4 555 # load the constant integer 555 (push 1)
    IL_0006: stfld int32 Person::personAge # store to field (pop 2)
    IL_000b: ret
```

The `ldind.ref` is the extra dereference, from a `ref Person` (a reference to a reference) to a `Person` (a reference).

Comment: "IL_0002: ldc.i4 555 # load the constant integer 555 (push 1)"

here we have ref-Person and we are directly accessing it's values? don't we need one more dereference to get to values(get to Person to access values, since we dereferenced once if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: @aka the LDC just pushes a value to the stack - we haven't touched the object yet; the semantics of stfld are "pop a reference to an instance, pop a value, store the value in the named field of the instance" - hence it is stfld that does the second dereference, as part of the store; that's why the same code if the type is a struct, when doing by-val, it will do "ldarga.0" (note the "a" for "address") to push a *ref* to the arg into the stack, and if you do by-ref it will do "ldarg.0" (no "a", so: the value) to push the value which is already a ref

Comment: Oops, "pop a value then pop a reference" (small but important order difference)

Comment: Can you clarify this part? In your struct example, passing struct by-val creates reference in the stack for argument which was created for local method(SendAPersonByReference in our case and argument is named p), but doesn't in case of value types there is no need for reference because it is directly in the stack and doesn't need pointing? and according to your explanation by-ref when you access the value by ldarg.0 you get the value which is in reality reference to the original struct?

Comment: @Aka structs are always *interacted with* via references, because the semantic is always "load N values (push onto the stack), do a thing (which pops those N things)"; if you had loaded (pushed)  the *actual struct*, then the "do a thing" would be to the *copy* on the stack, which is then discarded and gone. Hence: if we consider a non-ref SomeStruct parameter or local: you don't load the *value* of the parameter or local - you load the *address*, and then when the "do a thing" executes, we have updated the state *inside* the parameter or local. In the case of a `ref` parameter or local ...

Comment: ... we can just load the *value* which *is that reference*, and then when the "do a thing" executes, we have updated the state inside the original source location, which could be a parameter or local of a different method frame, an element in an array/span/unmanaged-buffer, or an "interior pointer" (for example a field of an instance somewhere). Make sense?

Comment: (note that in this, I mean when the struct type is the target of an operation, for example the target of a field access or a method call - basically when the type is going to be the `this` in some sense; this doesn't apply when the type is just being used as a value itself, i.e. onwards as a secondary parameter value)

Comment: Yes it totally makes sense, and as I understand changing state inside instance includes dereferencing right

Comment: Sorry for late question. In case of struct pass by value the reference of the copied struct variable is loaded on the stack right?

Comment: @Aka in the case of pass-by-value, then yes, it would use `ldarga` to load the *address* of the **local copy** on the current stack-frame

Answer (score 0):

`ref` only comes into play when you assign to or alter the variable itself, and the `p.personAge = 555;` statement *doesn't do that* in either sample. Yes, an assignment does happen  here, but not until after you first retrieve the object and then look up the `personAge` property on that object, which *happens without needing `ref`*.

A better example to understand the difference looks like this, assuming Person is a reference type (class) rather than value type (struct):

```
static void SendAPerson(Person p)
{
    p = new Person();
    p.personAge = 555;
}

static void SendAPersonByReference(ref Person p)
{
    p = new Person();
    p.personAge = 555;
}

static void SendAPerson2(Person p)
{
    p.personAge = 555;
}
```

With these new samples we need to think in terms of what happens in code that **calls** these methods, rather than in the methods themselves.

With the first (normal) method, *nothing changes* with the original Person variable used to call this method. The new object created in the method becomes eligible for garage collection as soon as the method ends, and the `555` value set in the method is lost.

With the second (reference) method, we *replaced* the contents of the original variable. It now holds our new object, with the `555` value in the `personAge` property. Any object that was there is now eligible for garbage collection (assuming no other extant references).

With the third (also normal) method, we change the `personAge` property on the provided object, rather than creating a new object, and this change is seen in the original object after the method completes.

Comment: In second case the p variable in behind the scenes holds address of the variable which the caller method passed right? So when we do ```p.personAge = 555;``` does the runtime does dereference twice(get to value referenced by p which is reference itself because it is reference type and then get to value which is pointed to by that reference variable in caller method? does that dereferencing happens automatically whenever the runtime sees the pointer(reference) in the code? and does ```p = new Person();``` this code goes to variable pointed by p and assigns new reference(pointer) to it?

Comment: @Aka There is no double reference. It's handled at the point where the method is called, so the method is working with the _same variable_ as the caller.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn but that *is* a double reference, assuming that `Person` is a `class`

Comment: So when runtime sees ref p parameter it just replaces it with the actual variable which was in the caller method?

Comment: "ref only comes into play when you assign to or alter the variable itself" - no, the fact that it is `ref` is relevant every time it is accessed